# pandas df.mean for multi-index across axis 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do you get the mean across axis 0 for certain mult-index `(index_col [1])`? I have

df:

```
         1   2   3 
 h   a   1   4   8
 h   b   5   4   6
 i   a   9   3   6
 i   b   5   2   5
 j   a   2   2   2
 j   b   4   4   4
```

I would like to create df1 - mean of 2nd index value across axis 0  ('a', 'b', 'a', 'b')

df1:

```
          1    2    3 
   0  a   4    3    5.3
   1  b   4.6  3.3  5
```

I know that I can select certain rows

```
df.loc[['a','b']].mean(axis=0)
```

but I'm not sure how this relates to multi-index dataframes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by second level with `mean`:

```
print (df.groupby(level=1).mean())
          1         2         3
a  4.000000  3.000000  5.333333
b  4.666667  3.333333  5.000000
```

And if necesary [`round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.round.html) values:

```
print (df.groupby(level=1).mean().round(1))
     1    2    3
a  4.0  3.0  5.3
b  4.7  3.3  5.0
```